# re.findall() returns empty list in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have python method defined as follows. I try to match dictionary elements which matches to   **clientname** parameter

```
def loadSites(self, fpath, clientname):

            keylist = [re.findall(clientname,k) for k in self.cacheDictionary.keys()]
            for items in keylist:
                print(items)
```

When I print the list I get;

```
['testClient']
['testClient']
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

I expect to get only two elements. What Im doing wrong here?

Also, how Can I delete that item from my dictionary?

Comment: And where is the dictionary it's list of list right ?

Comment: @RahulKP Yes..I fill  dictionary like //key = clientname + str(i)    
                self.cacheDictionary[key] = {'date_populated': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),'date_updated' :str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),'machine':'null'}//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns an empty `list` if the pattern is not found. You can simply [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) these out. Note that when you iterate a `dict`, you automatically iterate the keys:

```
keylist = filter(None, (re.findall(clientname,k) for k in self.cacheDictionary))
# Python3: if you want to persist a list
# keylist = list(filter(None, (re.findall(clientname,k) for k in self.cacheDictionary)))

for items in keylist:
    print(items)
```

#### Update:

If you want to delete all keys from the dict that match your pattern and in fact contain the string, there are many options tat do not require regular expressions, e.g.:

```
ks = [k for k in self.cacheDictionary if clientName in k]
for k in ks:
    self.cacheDictionary.pop(k)
    # del self.cacheDictionary[k]
```

Or just comprehend a new `dict` form scratch in one iteration:

```
self.cd = {k: v for k, v in self.cd.items() if clientName not in  k}
```

Comment: So It prints now  ['testcleint'] but when I try to delete I get   error//unhashable type: 'list'//     del self.cacheDictionary[items] . What is the right way to delete?

Comment: That's another question and if that's what you are trying to achieve, you shuold collect the keys themselves and not the results of `re.findall`

Comment: So How can I  get keys from this list returned from re.findall ?

Comment: Is `clientName` a regex pattern or just a simple string?

Comment: It is a string. My keys are populated like      
                key = clientname + str(i)

Answer (score 1):

If you want only two elements return only when there is a match.

```
keylist = [re.findall(clientname,k) if(re.findall(clientname,k)) else None for k in self.cacheDictionary.keys()]
        for items in keylist:
            print(items)
```

Comment: I think your if condition should come after for loop.

Comment: How to delete from the dictionary this key list? del self.cacheDictionary[items] gives //unhashable type: 'list'// error

Comment: try  `self.cacheDictionar.pop(items, None)`